# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I am newbiee to maven. I am trying to add JAXB2 plugin and dependencies to generate xml files from xsd. When I add underneath dependencies then a error is thrown under markers:-

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2: maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.7.4:generate(execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

The error is marked over  tag in jaxb2 plugin. I added this  tag in reference to solutions over internet, but nothing works.

My pom.xml looks like this:-

```
 <build>
    <finalName>PatternsWebapp</finalName>

    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--  This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. --> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.appfuse.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-warpath-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-classes</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                  <execution></execution>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>



    <plugins>
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <generatePackage>com.webapp.xml</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


    </plugins>


  </build>
```

Comment: hey guys, I got the solution to this problem. I just need to add m2e plugin for jaxb and that error is resolved.

Comment: +1 to both of you.This provides a great help.Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be resolved with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` 0.8.1 and m2e 1.1.

Comment: :Thanks for reply. But I resolved this problem by installing m2e connector for JAXB2 in eclipse from windows --> preference --> maven -->Discovery --> click "open catalog" --> install m2e connector for JAXB2

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that with newer versions you should no longer need this.

Comment: m2e connector for JAXB2 is no longer available actually!