# Sample Guestbook GAE Project - 'Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm new to programming (and web development) and thought it would be good practice to try and build the sample Google App Engine project through Google's tutorial.

Here are my notes, spanning vim/command line weirdness/other fun stuff -http://goo.gl/EfZ3Gm

For reference, I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 (beta)

I started here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

and followed all the command line instructions for Steps 1-3. I have Maven 3.2.5 installed, here is the output from my command prompt when I type 'mvn -v'

> Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T12:29:23-05:00)
>   Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5/libexec
>   Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

When I reach Step 4, I'd like to open the project in Eclipse, since I'm a bit more comfortable with looking at the code in an IDE.

Looking at the project's pom.xml file in the 'Overview' tab, I see the error -

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:display-plugin-updates (execution: default, phase: compile)

Looking at the code, I would guess it's because the maven referenced in the project doesn't match what I have installed on my machine? I see similar questions have been asked previously -

[Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843468/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration)

[Plugin error: execution not covered by lifecycle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391201/plugin-error-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration)

[Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593683/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration)

But running 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' in my terminal window would negate all the work I did in Steps 1-3 with maven in the command prompt; I needed maven for these steps. And the second option involves installing Spring IDE - there has to be a better way than this, I hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using eclipse with the m2e plugin (which is included standard and enables maven in eclipse), it will attempt to run plugins in your pom file as part of build for any maven enabled project.

For it to know what to do it uses an m2e-connector - there needs to be one for each plugin, installed into eclipse.

If it can't find one, it issues this error/warning.

If you press cmd-1 on the troublesome line, it will give you a few options. They boil down to 'ignore this'. One will modify your pom file to include a maven plugin which controls the configuration of eclipse, or add a clause to it if already present. The other saves the 'ignore this' configuration into eclipse settings.

This should remove the warning/error, and make no difference to your development environment.

In the case that this plugin is crucial, you'll need to locate an m2e-connector. They generally don't exist - so you'd probably be out of luck. In this case, it just spits out a report telling you if there are any more recent versions of dependencies available and has no impact on your build, so don't worry about it.

I strongly advise against using mvn eclipse:eclipse, especially with appengine apps. It won't use the correct library setup for your app to run properly.

Comment: Nick what would you recommend? Just curious. Eclipse tools seem to be pretty outdated

Comment: I use eclipse, but allow the native plugins to manage mapping a Pom to eclipse project setup. Basically add a maven and appengine configuration/nature. Or use IntelliJ.